# Suggest BAPI for transaction AS01

Tags: sap-erp, bapi

I am searching for a BAPI which covers the transaction `AS01`.
I have found two, but I am not sure which one to use:

- Either `BAPI_FIXEDASSET_CREATE` or `BAPI_FIXEDASSET_CREATE1` (where is the difference here)
- and `CREATE_ASSET`

Is it `BAPI_FIXEDASSET_CREATE` or another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is BAPI_FIXEDASSET_CREATE1.